# Ionic 2 Routing Not Working

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I just started learning Ionic 2, and I want to set up a page that goes to a tabbed view. I created a tabbed application, then added my own page called login. In my app.component.ts i added this:

```
  let self = this;
       var testing = <string> 'false';

       if (testing == 'true')
       {
         self.rootPage = TabsPage;
       }
       else
       {
         self.rootPage = LoginPage;
       }
```

then created a routes page called app.routes.ts and references it in my app.module.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [

    {path:'tabs', component: TabsPage},
    {path:'login', component: LoginPage},
    {path:'home', component: HomePage}

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {useHash: false})
    // RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],

  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {

}
```

now in my 'Login' page, that's the main page now, i want to click a button and go to the tabbed page. I added a button in the html view and this in my .ts file

```
goTo (){
        console.log('button clicked');
        this.router.navigate(['home']);
    }
```

but it throws this error :

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load
>   'HomePage'

how can i fix this ?

Comment: Do you have a `<router-outlet>` tag in your html?

Comment: @echonax no, my app.html contains <ion-nav [root]="rootPage">
</ion-nav>

Comment: I'm not familiar with ionic but according to the docs shouldn't you be using `public navCtrl: NavController` rather than router in your component?